# Python pygame need help on drawing rectangles

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to draw a rectangle using python's pygame module and i don't really know what im doing wrong

```
import pygame
import sys


white = 255, 255, 255
red = 255, 0, 0 
blue = 0, 0, 255
green = 0, 255, 0

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption('Rectangle test')

isRunning = pygame.get_init

while isRunning:
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.event.get()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            isRunning = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

    pygame.draw.rect(win, blue, (269, 165, 15, 15), 1)
    win.fill((255, 255, 255))

pygame.quit()
```

Thats the code that im currently using, it opens up the window, the window fill works as it should and the event.get also works, it prints what it should print but it doesnt draw any rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fill of the window is wiping out your rectangle.  Just make the two calls in the opposite order:

```
win.fill((255, 255, 255))
pygame.draw.rect(win, blue, (269, 165, 15, 15), 1)
```

and you'll see your rectangle.  I do when I run your code with this change applied.

Comment: wow thanks ive been trying to do this for at least 1 hour lol